# jquery validation plugin to check dates but not their placeholder text

Tags: jquery, validation, date, jquery-validate

I have inputs with placeholder values such as:

```
<input type="text" name="mydate" value="yyyy-mm-dd">
```

How can I change my rule to execute only if the value is not "yyyy-mm-dd" ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("form.myclasstovalidate").validate({
       rules: {    
    mydate: {
            date: true
               }
       }
 });
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you've got a problem cause your placeholder text is just a value in the input box which "imitates" the placeholder functionality. You probably remove it on click, bring it back if the user empties the content of the input box, of course make validation adjustments to not validate the placeholder as a real value and so on...

Instead all of the above-mentioned you can use the html5's [placeholder](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) attribute ;)

Answer (score 0):

using the placeholder attribute in your markup will solve your problem because it isn't an actual value it is a real placeholder and functions as one should. Your javascript has syntax errors also btw. I have fixed them in my answer.

```
<input type="text" name="mydate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" />

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("form.myclasstovalidate").validate({
       rules: {    
    mydate: {
            date: true
               }
       }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, if you prefer not to use the `placeholder` attribute, you can create a custom rule using [the plugin's `addMethod()` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage).  This is also a good lesson on how to create new rules even if an alternative approach is taken by the OP.

Since you stated you only want `date` validation to occur when the value is not `"yyyy-mm-dd"`, I simply added a conditional that checks the entered value against the element's [`defaultValue`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025), and placed the default `date` method/rule code inside.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("mydaterule", function (value, element) {
    if (value != element.defaultValue) {
        return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, 'please enter a valid date');
```

You can further tweak it as desired.

Apply the new rule as follows:

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        mydate: {
            mydaterule: true
        }
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/Acew7/**

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: `"yyyy-mm-dd"` is not the correct format to satisfy the default `date` rule.  However, `"yyyy/mm/dd"` will work.

e.g.

- 2013-02-28 will fail `date` validation
- 2013/02/28 will pass `date` validation